# jQuery .val() is returning .text() not .val()

Tags: jquery

I have this code

> ```
> <select id="month">
>     <option val='0'>January</option>
>     <option val='1'>February</option>
> </select>
> ```

I'm using this to try to get the values:

```
$month = $("#month option:selected").val();
```

But it's returning the text "January" and "February" not "0" or "1"

I tried this and got the same results:

```
$month = $("#month").val();
```

Comment: `.attr('val')` should works in your case, but better use `value` attrs

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The attribute should be `value`, not `val`:

```
<option value='0'>January</option>
<option value='1'>February</option>
```

When an option doesn't have a value attribute, the text is used as the default.